# Convert table image to Excel, using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conversion, image-processing, image-conversion

I have the table below in the image png file format.

Would it be possible to convert this to an Excel table using Excel?

[image]

Comment: If you have higher version like 365 the possible to convert into Table otherwise first covert it into PDF then to Excel ,,, lot's of Online free software are available to do this !

Comment: Of course if it is for this table - possibly you can just type it in (including grabbing the chinese) in a couple of minutes??

Comment: Try pasting into OneNote then converting in there, which has always been better at converting images to text than the other office apps, although recent versions of the apps have got better, including converting straight from camera images. If OneNote converts it to a nice table you will be able to copy paste that to Excel with little trouble.

Answer (score 1):

So far Excel for *Microsoft 365 for Mac*, Excel for *iPhone*, Excel for *Android tablets*, Excel for *Android phones* could [insert data from picture](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) into worksheets, **but this function could not support Chinese** according to the link.

I suggest you use some free online tools to scan pictures and convert them into Excel, such as https://web.baimiaoapp.com/image-to-excel. Maybe you could try it.

[image]

But please note that the free tools have a limit on number of pictures generally.